# c++ use of deleted function and implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: c++, struct, structure

i am a little bit with c++ and struct it is been more than 4 hours since i am trying to find the issue i had a code then i wanted use struct on it but somehow i gives me bunch of errors in the log which i couldn't solve it below.

the problem is with struct and union but i dont know exactly what is wrong

now this is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const double chicken_meal=3.50;
const double beef_meal=4.50;
const double supreme_meal=6.50;
const double jumbo_meal=8.0;
const double cheese=0.40;
const double medium_salad=1.50;
const double large_salad=2.5;
const double medium_drink=0.50;
const double large_drink=1.0;
const double medium_fries=0.50;
struct Meal1
{
    int choose_drink;
    int choose_salad;
    double total;
    char student;
    char select_salad;
    char select_extra_cheese;
    char choose_large_or_medium_drink;
    char choose_medium_fries;
    double chosen_drink=0.0;
    double chosen_fries=0.0;
    double chosen_salad=0.0;
    double chosen_cheese=0.0;
    double discount=0.0;
};
struct Meal2
{
    double total;
    int choose_drink;
    char student;
    char select_salad;
    char select_extra_cheese;
    char choose_large_or_medium_drink;
    char choose_medium_fries;
    int choose_salad;
    double chosen_drink=0.0;
    double chosen_fries=0.0;
    double chosen_salad=0.0;
    double chosen_cheese=0.0;
    double discount=0.0;

};
struct Meal3
{
    double total;
    double total_2;
    int choose_drink;
    char student;
    char select_salad;
    char select_extra_cheese;
    char choose_large_or_medium_drink;
    char choose_medium_fries;
    int choose_salad;
    int choose_burger_type;
    int second_meal;
    //output
    double chosen_drink=0.0;
    double chosen_fries=0.0;
    double chosen_salad=0.0;
    double chosen_cheese=0.0;
    double discount=0.0;
    string chosen_burger;
};
struct Meal4
{
    double total ;
    double total_2;
    int choose_drink;
    char student;
    char select_salad;
    char select_extra_cheese;
    char choose_large_or_medium_drink;
    char choose_medium_fries;
    int choose_salad;
    int choose_burger_type;
    int choose_bacon_mushroom;
    int second_meal;
    double payment;
    //output
    double chosen_drink=0.0;
    double chosen_fries=0.0;
    double chosen_salad=0.0;
    double chosen_cheese=0.0;
    double discount=0.0;
    string chosen_burger;
    string mushroom_or_bacon;
};
union Meal{
    struct Meal1 chicken_;
    struct Meal2 beef_;
    struct Meal3 supreme_;
    struct Meal4 jumbo_;
};
struct order
{
    int order_num;
    union Meal meals;
};
int main() {
    int choose;
    order dish;
//more code here but know need
//simple if else based on users choose
        return 0;
}
```

and this is my log:

```
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:106:11: error: use of deleted function ‘order::order()’
     order dish;
           ^~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:99:8: note: ‘order::order()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct order
        ^~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:99:8: error: use of deleted function ‘Meal::Meal()’
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:93:7: note: ‘Meal::Meal()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union Meal{
       ^~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:94:18: error: union member ‘Meal::chicken_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal1::Meal1()’
     struct Meal1 chicken_;
                  ^~~~~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:95:18: error: union member ‘Meal::beef_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal2::Meal2()’
     struct Meal2 beef_;
                  ^~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:96:18: error: union member ‘Meal::supreme_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal3::Meal3()’
     struct Meal3 supreme_;
                  ^~~~~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:97:18: error: union member ‘Meal::jumbo_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal4::Meal4()’
     struct Meal4 jumbo_;
                  ^~~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:99:8: error: use of deleted function ‘Meal::~Meal()’
 struct order
        ^~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:93:7: note: ‘Meal::~Meal()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union Meal{
       ^~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:96:18: error: union member ‘Meal::supreme_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal3::~Meal3()’
     struct Meal3 supreme_;
                  ^~~~~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:97:18: error: union member ‘Meal::jumbo_’ with non-trivial ‘Meal4::~Meal4()’
     struct Meal4 jumbo_;
                  ^~~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:106:11: error: use of deleted function ‘order::~order()’
     order dish;
           ^~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:99:8: note: ‘order::~order()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct order
        ^~~~~
/home/mani/CLionProjects/untitled3/main.cpp:99:8: error: use of deleted function ‘Meal::~Meal()’
CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/build.make:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled3.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'untitled3' failed
make: *** [untitled3] Error 2
```

Comment: use `std::variant` instead of `union`. You try to put non trivial type (`std::string`) in your `union` making it non default constructible.

Comment: Another thing: You don't need 4 classes; 2 should suffice.

Comment: You might narrow down the problem to `union U { std::string s; }; U u;`.

Comment: In C++ unions cannot contain classes, specifically any non-trivial class instance. See the linked question for more information. Either replace `std::string` with plain `char` arrays, and be diligent about bounds checking and undefined behavior, or use `std::variant`s instead of `union`s. Those are your two options.

Comment: Those structs  make very little sense. It loks a bit like you're confusing types with objects, unions with polymorphism, and are using member variables to do the work of local variables.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  after removing the string and char still the same issue i removed them just to see exactly what happens but sill the same

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry i didn't understand exactly what do i have to do in they way you mentioned

Comment: Basically: `using Meal = std::variant<Meal1, Meal2, Meal3, Meal4>;`

Comment: What you have to do is that instead of writing a such a huge pile of code and only afterwards try to compile the whole thing to see if it does, you should write only a few lines of code first, try to compile it, test it, and only if they work correctly you then write a few lines of code. Here, what you should've done is to write only a simple union of two plain structures, with one class member each. Try to compile it, once it works add a few more. This way when you get a compilation error you know exactly which lines caused it.